# Line spacing without using setpace - change line spacing for a single page

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

I have a problem. I want all texts to have 1.5 linespacing, so I use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`. The problem is that in one page (don't ask me why) the spacing has to be 1.0. If I use `setspace` package, it will reset spacing value in all pages. Is there any other ways to set line spacing different in one page?

Comment: Is there solution if I use setspace package to set everywhere linespacing to 1.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: 
Use `\usepackage{setspace}`

For figures and tables set next parameters:

```
\captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1.5}}  
\captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1.5}}
```

And for whole document set this:

```
 \linespread{1.5}
```

and for different line spacing for only one page use:

```
\begin{singlespace} 
text text xte

\end{singlespace}
```

And if you are doing new environment and add to there `\singlespace`, remember to add "enter", or "`\\`" or "`\par`" before `\end(*enviroment*}` so it will work....